# Почему выдает ошибку RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'on_ready' was never awaited в дискорд боте?

Tags: python, discord.py

Я делаю функцию в дискорд боте которая каждый день меняет аватарку и название сервера в определенное время, и бот выдает ошибку в указанное время. Как ее исправить?

Полная развертка ошибки:

RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'on_ready' was never awaited
self._run_job(job)
Object allocated at (most recent call last):
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/schedule/**init**.py", lineno 661
ret = self.job_func()

Скрипт:

```
servern = config.servernam
servera = config.serverava
#запуск и аватар
@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print(": Bot connected")
    server = bot.get_guild(967106046143365210)
    if servern is not None:
        servern1 = random.choice(servern)
        if servera is not None:
            servera1 = random.choice(servera)
            await server.edit(name = servern1, icon = servera1) #смена аватара

    def main():
        schedule.every().day.at("11:36").do(on_ready) #задержка
        while True:
            schedule.run_pending()

    if __name__ == '__main__':
        main()
```

Answer (score 0):

Почитайте подробнее [**зачем нужна функция `on_ready()`**](https://github.com/denisnumb/discord-py-guide/blob/main/discord-py.md#async-def-on_ready).

Если коротко, то

> Здесь нужно отметить, что в этой функции не следует размещать
> фрагменты кода, которые должны будут выполняться в дальнейшем, так как
> функция будет вызвана только один раз. Поэтому в этой функции можно
> разместить какое-либо сообщение, о том, что бот запущен и, если есть
> работа с данными из файлов, то самое время их подгрузить. *В общем,
> выполнить все единоразовые процедуры.*

---

Ваша проблема в том, что вы пытаетесь с помощью `schedule` синхронно вызывать асинхронную функцию `on_ready()`

```py
schedule.every().day.at("11:36").do(on_ready)
```

В то время как эту задачу можно решить встроенными методами `discord-py`

Подключаем модуль `discord.ext.tasks`. Устанавливаем цикл ожидания `24` часа. Перед тем как ждать 24 часа, дожидаемся нужного времени (11:36) в отдельной функции и уже после этого запускаем основную задачу.

```py
import asyncio
from discord.ext import commands, tasks
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

bot = commands.Bot("!")

@tasks.loop(hours=24)
async def my_task():
    # здесь смена иконки и названия

@my_task.before_loop
async def before_my_task():
    hour = 11
    minute = 36
    await bot.wait_until_ready()
    now = datetime.now()
    future = datetime.datetime(now.year, now.month, now.day, hour, minute)
    if now.hour >= hour and now.minute > minute:
        future += timedelta(days=1)
    await asyncio.sleep((future-now).seconds)

my_task.start()
```

**>** [**Исходный ответ**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61180222/14519908) **<**